# How can I change the TextView of the nav_header to the username after the user logged in with firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here is the code of the onCreate method of the MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,   R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    init();

    FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String userName =user.getDisplayName();

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
    textView.setText(userName);

}
```

I basically want that the Default TextView of the nav_header gets replaced with the logged in username. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Please only use the tag android-studio when your question/problem refers to the IDE Android-Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to access view of navigationView.

```
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.username);
textView.setText(userName);
```

Answer (score 0):

use sharepreferences to store the value here's simple class for putting and getting value on sharedpreferences to anywhere here's the simple class to achieve this

```
 public class SharedPreferenceUtils{

private static SharedPreferences prefs;
private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

  public static void init(Context context) {
    if (prefs == null) {
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
    }
}

public static void putString(String key, String value) {
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public static String getString(String key, String defValue) {
    return prefs.getString(key, defValue);
}}
```